# How to compile web application with any javac flag in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javac

I have a web application in which I want to retrieve method's parameter names with reflection `java.lang.reflect.Method.getParameters`. Howerver parameter names can be retrieved only if Java files were compiled with `-parameters` flag.

> You can obtain the names of the formal parameters of any method or
> constructor with the method
> java.lang.reflect.Executable.getParameters. (The classes Method and
> Constructor extend the class Executable and therefore inherit the
> method Executable.getParameters.) **However, .class files do not store
> formal parameter names by default**. This is because many tools that
> produce and consume class files may not expect the larger static and
> dynamic footprint of .class files that contain parameter names. In
> particular, these tools would have to handle larger .class files, and
> the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) would use more memory. In addition,
> some parameter names, such as secret or password, may expose
> information about security-sensitive methods.
>
> **To store formal parameter names in a particular .class file, and thus
> enable the Reflection API to retrieve formal parameter names, compile
> the source file with the -parameters option to the javac compiler**.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodparameterreflection.html

How to instruct Eclipse to compile my web application with `-parameters` so I could later start Tomcat server in Eclipse with my code compiled with `-parameters`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse has its own Java compiler and the equivalent of the `-parameters` flag can be set in ***Project > Properties: Java Compiler*** by ticking the last checkbox: ***Store information about method parameters (usable via reflection)*** (which is not enabled by default and requires Java 8 or higher).